# Fazer Marker Clusterer somar pontos por regiões do Brasil

Tags: google-maps

Fala galera, beleza?
Então.. tenho um mapa funcionando, porém está faltando apenas uma coisa para eu finalizar ele.

Atualmente, ao abrir o link, ele pega por estado no brasil, e soma todos.. mas eu queria que quando abri-se o mapa, ele pega-se por região e soma-se todos, e na medida que fosse dando zoom, ele pega-se por estado, cidade, e etc.

http://agfprojetos.cphost0016.servidorwebfacil.com/projetos/conif/

Estou usando o Marker Clusterer..
Alguém poderia me ajudar? Procurei aqui e no Google, porém não achei nada..

Valeus!!